# Android Studio 1.0.1 for mac not creating Gen folder and Eclipse not creating Blank activity no-matter what API level Selected

Tags: android, eclipse

I have had such a rough day, I have been trying to make an android using Android Studio 1.0.1 for Mac yet every time i create a new project the Gen folder which stores R.java is never created, I do not know, maybe its my installation, I was told to download android Build tools and i did. When i use Eclipse ADT Gen folder is created but Eclipse gives me trouble, I always fail to create blank activity no matter what API level i select, i have downloaded API 8, 21 and 14. Can someone please help me, I do not want to be using Eclipse, I prefer Android Studio for the wide Variety of Customization and tools.

Comment: do you see any errors ?

Comment: when I create lets say a button in the main xml, referencing it from the main activity fails because R.java is never generated in the Gen folder, which in the actual sense is never created from start, with Eclipse, it is always created but I always fail to create a blank activity, even when i use API level 24(Lollipop), and if i do it manually i get funny errors after such as the Gen folder disappearing and never showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Example Project and Eclipse magically worked, i guess it needed a bit of stretching, its working flawlessly for now, but am wondering if it will magically stop working again.